# Resizing window causes text to push down image

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

Take a look at the image to better understand what I'm saying.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLlX.png

how can I avoid this?

There were some examples showing text pushing up the image, but I tried messing with the vertical-align property and couldn't fix my issue.

```css
.jsinfo {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: rgb(33, 33, 80);
}

.jsimages{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px grey;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="jsinfo">1. Asks the user's name.<img class="jsimages" src="images/js1.png" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
    <div class="jsinfo">3. Comments on the amount of travel. Turns travel inputs into list.<img class="jsimages" src="images/js3.png" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="jsinfo">2. Greets the user and asks where they have traveled to.<img class="jsimages" src="images/js2.png" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
    <div class="jsinfo">4. Provides info about the word that is clicked.<img class="jsimages" src="images/js4.png" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Thanks!!!*

Comment: You should add the code or part the code

Comment: For best response, edit the answer to include your current CSS and HTML.

Comment: I will add some code right now

Comment: What is the real issue ? I don't see any issue in the screenshot provided

Comment: @Abinthaha As i resize the window, the text pushes the image on the left down since it takes up two line. I want the images to be aligned and the text to shift upward as it is squeezed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so without using custom CSS for the layout, you should place the text in a separate row, and the images in a separate row either. Look at the following example: (I haven't changed your CSS)

```css
.jsinfo {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: rgb(33, 33, 80);
}

.jsimages{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px grey;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <span class="jsinfo">1. Asks the user's name.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <span class="jsinfo">2. Greets the user and asks where they have traveled to.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLlX.png" alt="javascript implementation">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLlX.png" alt="javascript implementation">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <span class="jsinfo">3. Comments on the amount of travel. Turns travel inputs into list..</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <span class="jsinfo">4. Provides info about the word that is clicked.</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLlX.png" alt="javascript implementation">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaLlX.png" alt="javascript implementation">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code. Could you please confirm if it is what you are expecting as an output.

```css
.jsinfo {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: rgb(33, 33, 80);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.jsimages{
    width: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border:solid 1px grey;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    height: auto;    
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="jsinfo">
      <span>1. Asks the user's name.</span>
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://www.sabreakingnews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/lion.jpg" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
    <div class="jsinfo">
      <span>3. Comments on the amount of travel. Turns travel inputs into list.</span>
      <img class="jsimages" src="https://www.sabreakingnews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/lion.jpg" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="jsinfo">
      <span>2. Greets the user and asks where they have traveled to.</span>
    <img class="jsimages" src="https://www.sabreakingnews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/lion.jpg" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
    <div class="jsinfo">
      <span>4. Provides info about the word that is clicked.</span>
      <img class="jsimages" src="https://www.sabreakingnews.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/lion.jpg" alt="javascript implementation"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```